# What is the purpose of the Cognos SQL function/expression "ascii"?

Tags: sql, cognos-bi, impromptu

I must translate a Cognos Impromptu 7 query to TSQL. Part of the query includes the following:

```
nconvert((SUBSTRING((ascii(t1.TargetDate)) from 1 for 4)))

/* 
where: 
    t1 is a table alias
    TargetDate is a BIGINT contains the value 200501
*/
```

Can someone explain the purpose of the function/expression "ascii"?

(FYI: SQL Server ASCII function produces ascii(200501) ==> ascii(2) ==> 50 )

Bonus: If someone can point me to an online resource that includes the ascii definition, that would be appreciated. My search bore no fruit.

Comment: I found this IBM developerWorks resource, which suggests that ASCII function performs the same task as TSQL ASCII.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/db2-cert9188/section2.html

Answer (score 1):

The official Impromptu 7.5 administrator guide is in here: 
[Impromptu Administration Guide  7.5.0](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/c7bi/v7r5m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.impadmin.7.5.0.doc/impadmin.html) 
All functions (including text, numeric and Date / Time functions) are documented here 
However, I did not find any ascii function there. 
So, the second option is creating an IQD file: 
[Viewing SQL generated by Impromptu](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21348634) 
If this does not help. use SQL Server profiler to see the real SQL statement that impromptu sends: 
[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)